# labeling the nodes in the tree diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I am trying to labeling the nodes in the below diagram such that I just define the red(as x) and blue(as y) and the child node are named according to their path (e.g $-x^{2}y$ is two times moving to left from center along red direction and then one time in y direction upward.) I don't know if it is possible in tikz.
I also want to rotate it by 45 degree.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\xdef\mycolor{black}
\xdef\ColorList{{"red","blue"}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance= 32mm,sibling angle=90},
level 2/.style={level distance= 16mm,sibling angle=90},
level 3/.style={level distance = 8mm,sibling angle=90},
every node/.append style={fill},
set color/.code={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\index}{mod(#1,2)}
\pgfmathparse{\ColorList[\index]}
\xdef\mycolor{\pgfmathresult}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic, shape=circle,very thick,level 
distance=13mm,
                cap=round]
\node {} child [set color=\A,color=\mycolor] foreach \A in {0,1,2,3}
{ node {} child [set color=\A+\B+1,color=\mycolor] foreach \B in  {0,1,2}
    { node {} child [set color=\A+\B+\C+2,color=\mycolor] foreach \C in  {0,1,2}
        { node {} }
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really get how you translate the path into the name (as I understand it, some nodes would have the same name). But what you can do is use the variable `\A`, `\B` and `\C` to compute the coefficients you want, using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. For example, if you want the name of your node to be the number of blue lines in the path, you could write `node[scale=.5] { \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\blues}{mod(\A,2)+mod(\A+\B+1,2)+mod(\A+\B+\C+2,2)}\color{black}$\blues$}`. For the rotation, you can add `rotate=45` in the parameters of your tikzpicture. I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. **2nd EDIT**: I missed the fact that the minus sign is before `x` rather than in its exponent. Big thanks to Vinzza for pointing this out! Here is a version in which this is fixed, but it is very confusing since you cannot factor out the `-` without losing information.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\xdef\mycolor{black}
\xdef\ColorList{{"red","blue"}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=32mm,sibling angle=90},
level 2/.style={level distance=16mm,sibling angle=90},
level 3/.style={level distance =8mm,sibling angle=90},
every node/.append style={fill},
my color/.code={\pgfmathparse{\ColorList[mod(#1,2)]}
\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/color/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}},
set label/.code n args={3}{% x
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexpXA}{cos(180+#1*90)
+ifthenelse(#2==-1,0,cos(90+#1*90+#2*90))
+ifthenelse(#3==-1,0,cos(#1*90+#2*90+#3*90))}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mySignXA}{sign(\myexpXA)}
\ifnum\mySignXA<0
\def\Xsign{-}
\else
\def\Xsign{}
\fi
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexpX}{abs(\myexpXA)}
\ifcase\myexpX
\def\myX{}
\or
\def\myX{(\Xsign x)}
\or
\def\myX{(\Xsign x^2)}
\or
\def\myX{(\Xsign x^3)}
\fi
% y
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexpYA}{sin(180+#1*90)
+ifthenelse(#2==-1,0,sin(90+#1*90+#2*90))
+ifthenelse(#3==-1,0,sin(#1*90+#2*90+#3*90))
}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mySignYA}{sign(\myexpYA)}
\ifnum\mySignYA<0
\def\Ysign{-}
\else
\def\Ysign{}
\fi
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexpY}{abs(\myexpYA)}
\ifcase\myexpY
\def\myY{}
\or
\def\myY{(\Ysign y)}
\or
\def\myY{(\Ysign y^2)}
\or
\def\myY{(\Ysign y^3)}
\fi
\xdef\mylabel{\myX \myY}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,rotate=-45,shape=circle,very thick,level 
distance=13mm,cap=round]
\node {} child [my color=\A]  foreach \A in {0,1,2,3}
{ node[set label={\A}{-1}{-1},label=45:{$\mylabel$}] {} 
child [my color=\A+\B+1] foreach \B in  {0,1,2}
    { node[set label={\A}{\B}{-1},label={[font=\small,xshift=2pt,yshift=9pt]-135:$\mylabel$}] {} child [my color=\A+\B+\C+2] foreach \C in  {0,1,2}
        { node[set label={\A}{\B}{\C},
        label={[font=\tiny,yshift={-sin((\A+\B+\C)*90)*11pt},
        xshift={-cos((\A+\B+\C)*90)*2.5pt}]{(\A+\B+\C)*90}:$\mylabel\vphantom{x^2}$}] {} }
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**1st EDIT**: I missed the fact that there was [Vinzza's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449615/labeling-the-nodes-in-the-tree-diagram/449688#comment1129798_449615) when I wrote this answer. I used the rotate key, as suggested there, (though with a different sign) and also agree that the labels are not unique. On the other hand, I am not able to see the point of the modulo arithmetics there.

As for the question, I need your input for the labels. If I use the dimensions you give, they overlap (if printed in normal size). Here I solve the problem by making label fonts smaller, alternatives include making graph bigger, moving them closer to the bullets and/or using pins.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,snakes}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\xdef\mycolor{black}
\xdef\ColorList{{"red","blue"}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=32mm,sibling angle=90},
level 2/.style={level distance=16mm,sibling angle=90},
level 3/.style={level distance =8mm,sibling angle=90},
every node/.append style={fill},
my color/.code={\pgfmathparse{\ColorList[mod(#1,2)]}
\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/color/.expanded=\pgfmathresult}},
set label/.code n args={3}{%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexpXA}{cos(180+#1*90)
+ifthenelse(#2==-1,0,cos(90+#1*90+#2*90))
+ifthenelse(#3==-1,0,cos(#1*90+#2*90+#3*90))}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myexpYA}{sin(180+#1*90)
+ifthenelse(#2==-1,0,sin(90+#1*90+#2*90))
+ifthenelse(#3==-1,0,sin(#1*90+#2*90+#3*90))
}
\xdef\mylabel{x^{\myexpXA}y^{\myexpYA}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic,rotate=-45,shape=circle,very thick,level 
distance=13mm,cap=round]
\node {} child [my color=\A]  foreach \A in {0,1,2,3}
{ node[set label={\A}{-1}{-1},label=45:{$\mylabel$}] {} 
child [my color=\A+\B+1] foreach \B in  {0,1,2}
    { node[set label={\A}{\B}{-1},label={[font=\small,xshift=2pt,yshift=2pt]-135:$\mylabel$}] {} child [my color=\A+\B+\C+2] foreach \C in  {0,1,2}
        { node[set label={\A}{\B}{\C},
        label={[font=\tiny,yshift={-sin((\A+\B+\C)*90)*11pt},
        xshift={-cos((\A+\B+\C)*90)*2.5pt}]{(\A+\B+\C)*90}:$\mylabel$}] {} }
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice job ! :D As for the modulo arithmetics, I couldn't get the formular Touseef wanted (I still don't get the minus sign in his/her example $-x^{2}y$ but it might just be a mistake), so I just took what was already done with the color to make a small example! :) p.s.: you spelled my name badly, and it seems I can't ask for an edit for less that 6 letters... :/

Comment: @Vinzza Good point! I just happened not to read the question carefully enough.

Comment: Vinzza yes it was typo I mean $x^{-2}y$ and thank you @marmot :-)

Comment: @Touseef Sometimes it pays off being sloppy ;-)